# Can I convert a Microsoft Outlook PST file to CSV on the Mac without having Outlook installed

Tags: csv, outlook, pst

I have a Microsoft Outlook PST file.

However, I don't have Outlook installed.

Is it possible to generate a CSV file on the Mac without having Outlook installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.vcardexport.com/ but it's not free.